# How will my CLEP credits be viewed?

Tags: united-states, coursework, exams

I have taken 12 credits total in [CLEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/College_Level_Examination_Program) (College Level Examination Program) exams on order to bypass some general education requirements in humanities and basic sciences. I am in a program majoring in Physics and Engineering with a minor in Geosciences at a well-known state university.

My question is: How will my CLEP credits be viewed academically (i.e. when apply for grad school)? By potential employers? Will they be considered an asset or will they be seen as an inferior source of credits?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Academia.SE!  Can you please add an expansion of the acronym CLEP for those of us who aren't familiar with it?

Comment: There are similar college level examination programs in many countries. Please specify your location.

Answer (score 6):

No one is going to care about your CLEP credits for general education courses.  Your grades in major courses, your standardized test scores, letters of recommendation, and any research experience that you might have are for more important.